# CSS selector for a checked radio button's label

Tags: forms, css

Is it possible to apply a css(3) style to a label of a checked radio button?

I have the following markup:

```
<input type="radio" id="rad" name="radio"/>
<label for="rad">A Label</label>
```

What I was hoping is that

```
label:checked { font-weight: bold; }
```

would do something, but alas it does not (as I expected).

Is there a selector that can achieve this sort of functionality?  You may surround with divs etc if that helps, but the best solution would be one that uses the label ''for'' attribute.

It should be noted that I am able to specify browsers for my application, so best of class css3 etc please.

Answer (score 444, accepted):

try the `+` symbol:
It is Adjacent sibling combinator. It combines two sequences of simple selectors having the same parent and the second one must come **IMMEDIATELY** after the first.

As such:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label{ font-weight: bold; } 
 //a label that immediately follows an input of type radio that is checked
```

works very nicely for the following markup:

```
<input id="rad1" type="radio" name="rad"/><label for="rad1">Radio 1</label>
<input id="rad2" type="radio" name="rad"/><label for="rad2">Radio 2</label>
```

... and it will work for any structure, with or without divs etc as long as the label follows the radio input.

**Example:**

```css
input[type="radio"]:checked+label { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<input id="rad1" type="radio" name="rad"/><label for="rad1">Radio 1</label>
<input id="rad2" type="radio" name="rad"/><label for="rad2">Radio 2</label>
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this, but with the label being the prior element EG: `<label for="rad1">Radio 1</label><input id="rad1" type="radio" name="rad">`

Comment: You can use a tilda `~` to select siblings elements that aren't necessarily adjacent. http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: Thanks, this just helped me to create "image radio buttons" with no JS.

Comment: It's worth noting that this won't work in IE 8, since the `:checked` selector is [not supported](http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/).

Comment: @Martin Just in case you are wondering, This won't actually work in your case, since the label still needs to **follow** the input. The difference between '+' and '~' is whether the label is _directly_ adjacent, or is _generally_ adjecent: whether the label is the **next** element, or just **one of the next** elements.

Comment: Is there any way to style a radio button where there are no siblings, and the label either is an aunt or where you can style the parent which is a div?

Comment: A while back I saw a way to cause the label to display in front of the input radio button, even though the input was specified before its label something to do with float left on the label, but I don't remember where or all of the details.

Answer (score 158):

I know this is an old question, but if you would like to have the `<input>` be a child of `<label>` instead of having them separate, here is a pure CSS way that you could accomplish it:

```
:checked + span { font-weight: bold; }
```

Then just wrap the text with a `<span>`:

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="test" />
   <span>Radio number one</span>
</label>
```

See it on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gbq8Z/).

Comment: Excellent. This is very useful when dealing with the razor situation of `<label>@Html.RadioButtonFor(..) someText<label>`, I threw `<span>` around "someText" and it worked like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Nice! Hadn't thought of this.

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks.

Comment: What if you want to style :active label with :checked? This is not really a solution.

Comment: @MaciejKrawczyk It's not a solution *for you* because your use case is completely different. If you want to style an :active label you can just do `label:active { font-weight: bold; }`. See: http://jsfiddle.net/Gbq8Z/608/ (wow I can't believe that fiddle has been forked 608 times).

Comment: how can ı do this if checked radio, change label style on your code ?

Comment: @MustafaUysal Can you please clarify your question. I am having trouble what exactly you are asking.

Answer (score 34):

I forget where I first saw it mentioned but you can actually embed your labels in a container elsewhere as long as you have the `for=` attribute set. So, let's check out a sample on SO:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #262626;
  color: white;
}

.radio-button {
  display: none;
}

#filter {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.filter-label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid green;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

main {
  clear: left;
}

.content {
  padding: 3% 10%;
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.date {
  padding: 5px 30px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.filter-label:hover {
  background-color: #505050;
}

#featured-radio:checked~#filter .featured,
#personal-radio:checked~#filter .personal,
#tech-radio:checked~#filter .tech {
  background-color: green;
}

#featured-radio:checked~main .featured {
  display: block;
}

#personal-radio:checked~main .personal {
  display: block;
}

#tech-radio:checked~main .tech {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="featured-radio" class="radio-button" name="content-filter" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" id="personal-radio" class="radio-button" name="content-filter" value="Personal">
<input type="radio" id="tech-radio" class="radio-button" name="content-filter" value="Tech">

<header id="filter">
  <label for="featured-radio" class="filter-label featured" id="feature-label">Featured</label>
  <label for="personal-radio" class="filter-label personal" id="personal-label">Personal</label>
  <label for="tech-radio" class="filter-label tech" id="tech-label">Tech</label>
</header>

<main>
  <article class="content featured tech">
    <header>
      <h1>Cool Stuff</h1>
      <h3 class="date">Today</h3>
    </header>

    <p>
      I'm showing cool stuff in this article!
    </p>
  </article>

  <article class="content personal">
    <header>
      <h1>Not As Cool</h1>
      <h3 class="date">Tuesday</h3>
    </header>

    <p>
      This stuff isn't nearly as cool for some reason :(;
    </p>
  </article>

  <article class="content tech">
    <header>
      <h1>Cool Tech Article</h1>
      <h3 class="date">Last Monday</h3>
    </header>

    <p>
      This article has awesome stuff all over it!
    </p>
  </article>

  <article class="content featured personal">
    <header>
      <h1>Cool Personal Article</h1>
      <h3 class="date">Two Fridays Ago</h3>
    </header>

    <p>
      This article talks about how I got a job at a cool startup because I rock!
    </p>
  </article>
</main>
```

Whew. That was a lot for a "sample" but I feel it really drives home the effect and point: we can certainly select a label for a checked input control without it being a sibling. The secret lies in **keeping the `input` tags a child to only what they need to be (in this case - only the `body` element)**.

Since the `label` element doesn't actually utilize the `:checked` pseudo selector, it doesn't matter that the labels are stored in the `header`. It does have the added benefit that since the `header` is a sibling element we can use the `~` generic sibling selector to move from the `input[type=radio]:checked` DOM element to the `header` container and then use descendant/child selectors to access the `label`s themselves, **allowing the ability to style them when their respective radio boxes/checkboxes are selected**.

Not only can we style the labels, but also style other content that may be descendants of a sibling container relative to all of the `input`s. And now for the moment you've all been waiting for, the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/TheThinker/ckev3tt0/)! Go there, play with it, make it work for you, find out why it works, break it, do what you do!

Hopefully that all makes sense and fully answers the question and possibly any follow ups that may crop up.

Comment: This is the answer to this question. Other ones while correct are essentially super basic. While this solves something more complicated and interesting, that one would be tempted to grab js for.

Comment: The accepted answer to this question has >30x as many upvotes despite imposing a limitation that this answer totally obviates. Unlike many similarly-hyped posts that purport mind-blowing info, this actually delivers on the claim. Amazing work, thanks so much.

Comment: @naughtilus - this answer totally obviates the simple answer's limitation, because it explicitly defines the styles for each option. i.e. Mine constrains you to having a structure convention; this one constrains you to writing css for every radio button and result.

Comment: @morphles simple != "super basic": this solution is more complicated, interesting and powerful - for this exact code; mine will work on all pages following 1 convention

Answer (score 10):

If your input is a child element of the `label` and you have more than one labels, you can combine [@Mike's trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431726/css-selector-for-a-checked-radio-buttons-label/17206675#17206675) with `Flexbox` + `order`.

[image]

```css
label.switchLabel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 150px;
}
.switchLabel .left   { order: 1; }
.switchLabel .switch { order: 2; }
.switchLabel .right  { order: 3; }

/* sibling selector ~ */
.switchLabel .switch:not(:checked) ~ span.left { color: lightblue }
.switchLabel .switch:checked ~ span.right { color: lightblue }



/* style the switch */

:root {
  --radio-size: 14px;
}

.switchLabel input.switch  {
  width: var(--radio-size);
  height: var(--radio-size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: inherit;
  -moz-appearance: inherit;
  appearance: inherit;
  
  box-shadow: calc(var(--radio-size) / 2) 0 0 0 gray, calc(var(--radio-size) / 4) 0 0 0 gray;
  margin: 0 calc(5px + var(--radio-size) / 2) 0 5px;
}

.switchLabel input.switch:checked {
  box-shadow: calc(-1 * var(--radio-size) / 2) 0 0 0 gray, calc(-1 * var(--radio-size) / 4) 0 0 0 gray;
  margin: 0 5px 0 calc(5px + var(--radio-size) / 2);
}
```

```html
<label class="switchLabel">
  <input type="checkbox" class="switch" />
  <span class="left">Left</span>
  <span class="right">Right</span>
</label>
```

asd

html

```html
<label class="switchLabel">
  <input type="checkbox" class="switch"/>
  <span class="left">Left</span>
  <span class="right">Right</span>
</label>
```

css

```css
label.switchLabel {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 150px;
}
.switchLabel .left   { order: 1; }
.switchLabel .switch { order: 2; }
.switchLabel .right  { order: 3; }

/* sibling selector ~ */
.switchLabel .switch:not(:checked) ~ span.left { color: lightblue }
.switchLabel .switch:checked ~ span.right { color: lightblue }
```

See it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bz6hcLez/1/).

*note: Sibling selector only works within the same parent. To work around this, you can make the input hidden at top-level using [@Nathan Blair](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431726/css-selector-for-a-checked-radio-buttons-label/43132408#43132408) hack.*

Answer (score 2):

For my case, where is the radio input inside the label element like the following code:

```html
<label>
    <input type="radio">
</label>
```

the proper css selector is:

```css
label:has(input[type="radio"]:checked) {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Answer (score -7):

UPDATE:

This only worked for me because our existing generated html was wacky, generating `label`s along with `radio`s and giving them both `checked` attribute.

Never mind, and big ups for Brilliand for bringing it up!

If your label is a sibling of a checkbox (which is usually the case), you can use the `~` sibling selector, and a `label[for=your_checkbox_id]` to address it... or give the label an id if you have multiple labels (like in this [example](http://codepen.io/istro/pen/daker) where I use labels for buttons)

---

Came here looking for the same - but ended up finding my answer in the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors).

a `label` element with `checked` attribute can be selected like so:

```
label[checked] {
  ...
}
```

I know it's an old question, but maybe it helps someone out there :)

Comment: And how is the label supposed to become checked?

Comment: Hey, good catch. It doesn't. Apparently we have some pretty wacky code that generates labels along with radio buttons, and adds a "checked" attribute to both when generating the html. But it's not really valid... So this is totally unusable. I'll edit the answer, I have no clue why I got the upvotes for it. Thanks!