# Highlight label if checkbox is checked

Tags: html, css

Is there a non-javascript way of changing the color of a label when the corresponding checkbox is checked?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector for a checked radio button's label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431726/css-selector-for-a-checked-radio-buttons-label)

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Use the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator):

```css
.check-with-label:checked + .label-for-check {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="check-with-label" id="idinput" />
  <label class="label-for-check" for="idinput">My Label</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not work in IE 6-8,  unless OP do not care about IE.

Comment: I know, I noted that it would only work in modern browsers in my answer.

Comment: @inf3rno It should. Both the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) and [`:checked` selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/:checked) are listed as supported in IE9. [Microsoft's own docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx) confirm this.

Comment: good solution, but if the label element ist not the next ancestor you should try using the ~ selector instead of the + selector http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200601/css_3_selectors_explained/ (last in table)

Comment: @abimelex Though depending on your HTML that may end up matching many more `<label>`s than desired.

Comment: This didn't work for me because my label tag was not next to my input tag. Moving them in the code to be next to each other fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: The label is missing the 'for' attribute so the elements are not related. The CSS trick will work but the checkbox won't be triggered by clicking on the label. After that is fixed you only need

[type=checkbox] + label {/* styles */}

Comment: This only works when `<label>` follows  the checkbox; if the `<label>` tag wraps the checkbox then there appears to be no CSS way of getting it to work. (E.g. to change the background colour of the box that surrounds both the checkbox and the label, see http://jsfiddle.net/ttL49ce9/ )

Comment: @DarrenCook Nope, because there’s no way in CSS for a parent to change based on a child (except via certain implicit changes like size).

Comment: Assuming the label and checkbox are adjacent like this, though.

Comment: This is beautiful. One day CSS will become the reason of D3's demise.

Answer (score 117):

I like Andrew's suggestion, and in fact the CSS rule only needs to be:

```
:checked + label {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

I like to rely on implicit association of the `label` and the `input` element, so I'd do something like this:

```
<label>
   <input type="checkbox"/>
   <span>Bah</span>
</label>
```

with CSS:

```
:checked + span {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wrumsby/vyP7c/

Comment: There's a trick for changing the background color of the *parent label* of a checked checkbox. Make the label overflow: hidden, then give the checkbox a very large dropshadow... `:checked { box-shadow: 0 0 0 500px orange; }`. You'll need to play with z-indexes to ensure any sibling elements aren't hidden.

Answer (score 12):

This is an example of using the `:checked` pseudo-class to make forms more accessible. The `:checked` pseudo-class can be used with hidden inputs and their visible labels to build interactive widgets, such as image galleries. I created the snipped for the people that wanna test.

```css
input[type=checkbox] + label {
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: #0964aa;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cb_name" name="cb_name"> 
<label for="cb_name">CSS is Awesome</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is the code to change the label color to green of the checkbox,when it is checked.

```css
input[type=checkbox]:checked +label{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="yes" />
<label for="yes">Yes</label>
```

input and label are the adjacent sibling tags, selector "+" is used to define the sibling relation between them moreover, ":checked" is a pseudo class in CSS,a CSS pseudo-class is a keyword added to a selector that specifies a special state of the selected element(s),so for us the checked state is considered.

Answer (score -31):

You can't do this with CSS alone. Using jQuery you can do

**HTML**

```
<label id="lab">Checkbox</label>
<input id="check" type="checkbox" />
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight{
    background:yellow;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#check').click(function(){
    $('#lab').toggleClass('highlight')
})
```

This will work in all browsers

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/LgADZ/

Comment: The question did say a non javascript way and the answer before you cleary showed a way that works using only css

Comment: The accepted solution uses the [adjacent sibling selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors) which is actually a feature of [CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/).

Comment: JQuery is the only solution that will ensure cross browser support.

Comment: Please be careful there Hussein. You can provide support for browsers like Internet Explorer 6 that don't support the adjacent sibling selector using **JavaScript**. **jQuery** is a JavaScript library that will help you do this; there are other libraries (or even pure JavaScript!) that you can do this with.

Comment: Re: my earlier comment, I did not realise that the [`:checked` pseudo selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#checked) is a CSS3 feature.

Comment: Though its not the exact answer asked by the @WalterRumsby but its the recommended answer, as events, clicks are not supposed to be handled by css, its just experimental feature you could do with css. So better to avoid such approach in almost all cases.

Comment: While this is considered a workaround, I think that it should be removed from this discussion.