# css styling when click on checkbox

Tags: css

I want to style the div#main in the following code when I click on the checkbox inside it. Can I do this using only css/css3? Thank you in advance!

```
<div id="main">
<div id="content">
<input type="checkbox"/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: here is the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275857/highlight-label-if-checkbox-is-checked-html-css

Comment: No. you can style the `div` only if it's a later sibling of the checkbox.

Comment: no, this styles the label, not the parent div

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can play with HTML & css. Write Like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="change"/>
<div id="main">
<div id="content">
<label for="change"></label>
    <h2>hello</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background:red;
  text-align:center;
}
input{
    display:none;
}
input:checked ~ #main{
    border:2px solid green;
    font-size:24px;
    background:yellow;
}
input:checked ~ #main label{
    background:url(http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5182/5840005274_b3bcc52bb1_o.png);
}


label{
    background:url(http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2793/5839457953_1690178a65_o.png);
    display:block;
    width:18px;
    height:18px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/j5nTx/

Comment: I think that's the only way of doing it using CSS only.

Comment: thanks. it took me a few minutes to understand why it works. it might be nice to explain that the <label for="..."> can be placed separately to the input checkbox and is also clickable. This saves the need for any JS click handlers. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6293626

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<input type="checkbox" class="checkBox"/>
```

CSS

```
.checkBox:checked
{
/* apply any css */
border:solid 1px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't style the `div `.

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```
#main #content input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
    /*your styles*/
}
```

​if you want style to #main #content you should use jquery :

```
$(function () {
            $("#chk").change(function () {
                if ($(this).is(":checked"))
                    $("#content").addClass("newClass");
                else {
                    $("#content").removeClass("newClass");
                }
            });
        });
```

CSS :

```
.newClass{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: this styles the checkbox, not the parent div

Comment: I would say using `#main #content` is a bit redundant, as the id is always unique.

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked #content {
    /*your color changing code*/
}
```

it applies the style code to `#content` when   `input[type="checkbox"]` is cheked i.e what you want

Comment: Space implies the div is a descendant of the checkbox. It isn't. It can't be.