# Checking a checkbox by clicking an image with changing image opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, checkbox

i have a image with checkbox, i used this code for Checking a checkbox by clicking an image...

```
<label for="img1"><img class="img" src="myimage.jpg" /></label>
<input type="checkbox" class="chk " checked="checked" id="img1" name="img1" value="0" />
```

its working fine, my question is, i want when checking check box above image opacity will be `0.5` or display a extra `div` over this image  and when Un check above image opacity return to `1.0` or remove that div if we use div, any idea.???

thanks

Comment: This has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275857/highlight-label-if-checkbox-is-checked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can accomplish this using some advanced CSS selectors provided that the `<label>` is the checkbox. The `~` selector is called general sibling selector and will match all sibling after the element.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/5euSB/)

**CSS**

```
input:checked ~ label {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk " checked="checked" id="img1" name="img1" value="0" />
<label for="img1">
    <img class="img" src="https://www.google.com.au/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
</label>
```

### Support

Support for `:checked` is only present for IE9 and above, if you need support for IE8 then you can you use a `.checked` class as use it in addition to the CSS3 `:checked` selector.

**JS**

```
$('#img1').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('checked');
});
```

**CSS**

```
input:checked ~ label,
input.checked ~ label {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

For support < IE8 then you should use a more general JavaScript solution.

```
$('#img1').click(function () {
    $('label[for=' + this.id + ']').toggleClass('checked');
});

label.checked {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: its working fine... one question this CSS property supported all major browsers...??

Comment: From IE9 and above, if you want support earlier than that it needs to be done with javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/:checked

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.img').click(function() {
    if ($('#img1').is(':checked'))
        $(this).css('opacity', 0.5);
    else
        $(this).css('opacity', 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.img').click(function() {
    $(this).css('opacity', $('#img1').is(':checked')?0.5:1.0);
});
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. Good answers usually have some text explaining what the code is doing. That will help people who don't understand what you're doing.