# jQuery select checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am using jquery to select checkbox on and off when user click on image.

Here is my code:

```
function clickimage(e){
    chkbox = e.parent().children('.chkBox');
    if(chkbox.is(":checked")){
        chkbox.attr('checked', false);
    }else{
        chkbox.attr('checked', true);
    }
}
```

When I first click on image, the checkbox does checked. When I click on image again, the checkbox is unchecked. But the problem is after that, the checkbox will never be selected again.

I try to verify `chkbox.is(":checked")` and it does return `false` value. I put the checking code after `chkbox.attr('checked', true);`, it also return false value.

Why is it like that? How can I fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: can you share the html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
function clickimage(e){
    chkbox = e.parent().children('.chkBox');
    if(chkbox.is(":checked")){
        chkbox.prop('checked', false);
    }else{
        chkbox.prop('checked', true);
    }
}
```

You should use `.prop()` and not `.attr()`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need Javascript for this.

Just put the image into a `label`.

**[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pAYFa/289/)**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried with label. But it doesn't work well on IE8 for my case. That's why I am thinking to use javascript to do the job.

Comment: No problem. I think this question with provided accepted answer is of interest for you then: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15740206/checking-a-checkbox-by-clicking-an-image-with-changing-image-opacity

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if(chkbox.is(":checked")){
    chkbox.removeAttr('checked');
}else{
    chkbox.attr('checked', 'checked');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 function clickimage(e){
  chkbox = e.parent().find('.chkBox');
  if(chkbox.is(":checked")){
     chkbox.attr('checked', false);
   }else{
      chkbox.attr('checked', true);
   }
 }
```