# custom checkbox with tabing highlight

Tags: jquery, html, css

i need to creat checkbox like this :

i need to use this check mark in checkbox : https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfplA.png

[image]

what i tried is here :

```
<style>
        .myCheckbox input {
            display: none;
        }

        .myCheckbox span {
            width: 20px;
            height: 20px;
            display: block;
            background: gray;
        }

        .myCheckbox input:checked + span {
            background: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfplA.png");
        }
    </style>

 <input id="Text1" type="text" style="width:150px" tabindex="0" />
    <input id="Text1" type="text" style="width:150px" tabindex="1" />
    <input id="Text1" type="text" style="width:150px" tabindex="2" />
    <label class="myCheckbox">
        <input type="checkbox" name="test" tabindex="3" />
        <span></span>
    </label>
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" style="width:150px" tabindex="4" />
```

but it is not highlighting when we press the tab, and when i check the background gray is lost,

thanks for help in advance.

**here is my code** : http://jsfiddle.net/KM6w7/

Comment: You should use a transparent png

Comment: is transparent png already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To style your custom checkbox (which is actually a `label`), you have to make the label **focusable**. I don't think of any other way than setting the `contenteditable` attribute to `true` and setting the `font-size` to `0` to hide the caret. However we need script to prevent user from being able to type characters (especially the <kbd>backspace</kbd> key). The script is also needed to toggle (simply by triggering the `click`) the checkbox when user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Space</kbd> (this is the normally behavior of checkbox when being in focus state). Here are the code details:

```
$('.myCheckbox').keydown(function(e){      
   //check if the pressed key is Enter or Spacebar
   //then trigger the click() on the inner span to toggle the checkbox
   if(e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode == 32){
     $('span', this).click();        
   }
   //check if the pressed key is not TAB, then cancel the keydown
   //We won't cancel the TAB because it helps switch 
   //the focus to the next element.
   if(e.keyCode != 9) return false;
});
```

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/KM6w7/3/)

**NOTE**: Now your `label` can be focusable, so you can use the `:focus` to style the inner span like this:

```
.myCheckbox:focus > span {
   ...
}
```

I also added the custom style for focus state, however I commented out all because you can use the default ***outline*** style.

**UPDATE**: Because we always have to use script, so I think you can replace the `label` with a `button` (which supports focusability by default), so the script will be much shorter/more concise. Code details:

**HTML**:

```
<button class="myCheckbox" tabindex='4'>
  <input type="checkbox" name="test"/>
  <span></span>
</button>
```

**CSS**:

```
.myCheckbox {
  width:20px;
  height:20px;
  padding:0;
}
.myCheckbox:focus {
  border:1px solid orange;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$('.myCheckbox').click(function(){
  $('input',this).click();
});
```

## [Demo 2.](http://jsfiddle.net/3xGjX/)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the gray background is lost when you check the checkbox is that the image you are using for green check have white background.

For highlighting check this: [Highlight label if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275857/highlight-label-if-checkbox-is-checked)

For highlighting checkbox border:

```
    input[type=checkbox]
    {outline: 2px solid #c00;}
    input[type=checkbox] { background:transparent;border:0; margin-top: 2px;}
```

check this: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PCD6f/7/)

Comment: i wan to highlight checkbox border if we do the tab

Answer (score 0):

Adding (!important) made it work for me

Html:-

```
     <input type="checkbox"  id="StemClipped" name="StemClipped" tabindex="339" value="true" @(Model.StemClipped ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "")
```

Css:-

```
     input[type="checkbox"]:focus{ 
     outline: 2px solid #000 !important
     }
```