# Is there something similar to :checked for input type text?

Tags: jquery, css

Some questions.

1. Is there some CSS selector similar to :checked to "evaluate" if an input type="text" is empty or not?
2. If there isn't, is there a Jquery alternative? To be more specific I want to stylize the following element after a "Non empty" input. I should probably only assign a class into this input: `class="NotEmpty"` and then prepare a CSS `.NotEmpty+p {}`, right?
3. What could be the reason to have a checked selector and not other similar options?

Comment: You may have a look at this url [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275857/highlight-label-if-checkbox-is-checked)

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854556/check-if-inputs-are-empty-using-jquery

Comment: No, in practice you need a script to accomplish that

Comment: Humm. Yeap. I was just thinking in terms of styling, but a "validation" aproach is interesting...

Answer (score 2):

In practice such a selector would iterate over all elements.

So just do it yourself using [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var $collection = $("some selector").filter(function(){ return this.value });
```

Comment: Thanks for answering that fast. I extended a bit the original question. :o)

Answer (score 2):

jQuery doesn't have such selector. There is an `:empty` selector but it works by checking element's descendants.

As the other answer shows you can use the `.filter` method for checking the matching elements. But if you want to use a selector you can add one. Here is an example:

```
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
    empty_field: function(a) {
        return typeof a.value === 'string'
               && a.value.trim().length === 0;
    }
});
```

The selector can be used like the predefined selectors:

```
// select the empty inputs:
$('input:empty_field');
// select the not-empty inputs:
$('input:not(:empty_field)');
```