# How to highlight label if checkbox is checked but set up is label first then input?

Tags: css

[Highlight label if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275857/highlight-label-if-checkbox-is-checked)

A totally different set up from the above link.

set up 1:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
<label>Text</label>
```

answer:

```
input:checked + label { font-weight: bold; }
```

set up 2:

```
<label>Text</label>
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

answer:

```
??
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a hack.

- Begin with HTML element order reversed
- Wrap elements in `flexbox`
- Style as usual with `+` or `~`
- Restore desired order via `order: -1`;
- Make sure to point that `label` to a valid `id`

[image]

```css
.container {
  display: flex; 
}

[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  color: red;
}

label {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input id="mycheckbox" type="checkbox" checked> 
  <label for="mycheckbox">Text</label>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x2czhewb/2/)