# Select :after pseudo from child by using '+' selector

Tags: css

Is it possible to select parent :after pseudo class from child by using '+' selector.

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <span class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.parent:after{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
}

.child + :after{ // targeting parent after
    background-color: red;
}
```

EDIT: To explain what I wanted to achieve - basically, I wanted to change label:after styling when checkbox is checked.

HTML:

```
<label class="parent">
    <!--label:before-->
    Click me to check me
    <input class="child">
    <!--label:after-->
</label>
```

Comment: No...because it's not an **element** it's styling and so can't be selected like that.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: considering the fact that after is always *after* all the elements, you don't need any selector. Applying background-color:red to after is enough

Comment: With the + selector you are not even selecting neither the child or the parent. you are selecting the next element on the same "level". There is no selector for a parent element.

Comment: @Paulie_D I just wanted to create CSS checkbox by having input inside label. When checkbox is checked it would restyle the label:after.
label > checkbox + label:after

Comment: @RacoonOnMoon 
Level 1: label; Level 2: label:before, input[type=checkbox], label:after - checkbox and label:after are on the same level

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that it would be a *parent selector* and those don't exist, yet!

Comment: Its ways better to ask what you **actually** want rather than give *pseudo-code*, it will get you more accurate answers quicker.

Comment: @Paulie_D yeah, sry for that. I edited the question. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Take a look at this asnwer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275857/highlight-label-if-checkbox-is-checked you can just add after/before .check-with-label:checked + .label-for-check:after, html changes needed

Comment: Well thats OK but there is no answer because as I said, there is no parent selector. So what you want is not possible without changing the hTML

Comment: @RacoonOnMoon I know there are other ways to achieve what I wanted, but my question is not how to achieve it. I just wanted to know if it is possible to select pseudoclasses this way. Still...thank you for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to select and change the parent style from the child [July of 2020]. it would be awesome if they add it to CSS! for more info check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).

so I think you change the structure of your HTML to achieve what you want. take a look at this working example:

HTML:

```
<div class="checkbox-container">
  <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" />
  <label for="checkbox"></label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.checkbox-container label {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .checkbox-container label::after {
    content: 'foo';
    color: #fff;
  }

  .checkbox-container input {
    display: none;
  }

  .checkbox-container input:checked + label::after {
    content: 'bar';
    background-color: red;
  }
```

basically you need to put `label` and `checkbox` at the same level. having a wrapper element (in this case `div` element) is optional.