# How to use pure CSS (no JS) to control the style of a label about a checkbox?

Tags: html, css

I have a HTML checkbox, with a `<input type="checkbox">` and a `<label>` like this:

I want to style the label according to the check status of the `checkbox` element. Is it possible to use **pure CSS** to do that? How can I do that?

For instance, I want to hide the checkbox dot and use the label style to save some room on the page:

[image]

Comment: yes it's possible

Comment: yes, of course you can. there are many ready-made examples on the Internet

Comment: How do I do that? Thanks

Comment: [Duplicate](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+css+style+label+based+on+checkbox+state) of [Highlight label if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275857/highlight-label-if-checkbox-is-checked). What have you tried so far? What research have you done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:checked` CSS pseudo-class selector represents any radio / checkbox / option element that is checked or toggled to an ON state.

You might want to read more about it on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked).

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<input id="label1" type="checkbox" name="label"/><label for="label1">Label 1</label><br />
<input id="label2" type="checkbox" name="label"/><label for="label2">Label 2</label>
```