# Click event on label not firing (class doesn't change)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a checkbox inside a label. I added the event listener for the click event to the label, so as to trigger the class.

It does work when I click the checkbox.

However, if I click the label, nothing changes. Why is that, considering that the event is binded to the label and not the checkbox?

```js
const formCheck = document.querySelector('.drinos-checker')

formCheck.addEventListener('click', function () {
    formCheck.classList.toggle('checkerActive')
})
```

```css
.checkerActive {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
   <label class="drinos-checker"><input class="drinos-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value">Renovation</label>
```

Comment: You can probably achieve this with just CSS see: [Highlight label if checkbox is checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5275857/highlight-label-if-checkbox-is-checked)

Comment: That would only work if the label comes immediately after the checkbox, in my case label wraps the input, but thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this simple example:

```js
const formCheck = document.querySelector('.check')

formCheck.addEventListener('click', function () {
   console.log("clicked!")
})
```

```html
<input class="check" type="checkbox">
```

When you check the checkbox, you can see that the event is captured and then logged.

#### What happens if we then add a label?

Let's do that. If we then leave the code unchanged, appears that a click on a label **does also trigger** our click event, though it was binded to the checkbox.

```js
const formCheck = document.querySelector('.check')

formCheck.addEventListener('click', function () {
   console.log("clicked!")
})
```

```html
<label><input class="check" type="checkbox">A label</label>
```

That's how it works. But we're not finished yet...

#### What happens if I bind the event on the label, not on the checkbox?

```js
const formCheck = document.querySelector('label');

formCheck.addEventListener('click', function () {
   console.log("clicked!")
})
```

```html
<label><input class="check" type="checkbox">A label</label>
```

You have seen that correct: the click event triggers two times. But how is it even possible? Let's break down what happens here:

- the label works this way that it triggers a click event in the checkbox
- once you click the label, the event that you binded is triggered
- but since the label itself "clicks" the checkbox, the event is triggered again, because the checkbox is in the label. This way, the event is called **twice**.

##### So, what does it mean?

You may have understood that already: the class doesn't change because it toggles two times on a single click. I.e. it toggles and then immediately toggles again, which results in you not noticing any changes.

#### How can one fix that?

There's a quick fix: you could replace your click event with change event. This way:

- the label triggers checkbox
- the change event on checkbox is called
- the label itself doesn't have a change event, thus everything works as intended

#### "Working-as-intended" example:

```js
const formCheck = document.querySelector('.drinos-checker')

formCheck.addEventListener('change', function () {
    formCheck.classList.toggle('checkerActive')
})
```

```css
.checkerActive {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="drinos-checker"><input class="drinos-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value">Renovation</label>
```

Comment: thanks for the explenation, I have another problem I think you could help me understand. I have a parent div with checkboxes wrapped in labels, I have added an event listener to the parent and made it in a way that if the parent is clicked we simply return; and if not the active class is added to the label, everything works fine expect when I actually click on the little box, it triggers the class but it triggers it to the input itself and not the label (where its suppossed to be)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of adding click event to the `label`, add it to the `input` element -

```js
const formCheck = document.querySelector('.drinos-checker');
const inputCheck = document.querySelector('input');

inputCheck.addEventListener('click', function() {
  formCheck.classList.toggle('checkerActive')
})
```

```css
.checkerActive {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<label class="drinos-checker"><input class="drinos-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value">Renovation</label>
```

Comment: This would be the correct solution, danke

Comment: This answer works, however it does not explain the core reason