# whats the CSS selector for a label that does not have a sibling input type=checkbox||radio?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to set it with CSS, not jquery.

The selector is for

> all labels which do not have a sibling that is a checkbox or radio component.

a sample is:

```
<span>
  <input id="item" type="checkbox">
  <label for="item">Data</label>
</span>
```

This is because i have CSS which sets label to 12px, BUT it affects asp:checkboxes and asp:radio..., but i do not want them to be affected.

Comment: You may add a class for these labels.

Comment: Why not set this as the default style, then apply a selector to the labels that DO have a sibling?

Comment: @Diodeus: Because you can't do that either. You can select based on whether an element has any siblings or not, but you can't select based on what kind of siblings it has.

Comment: the CSS file is for 150 aspx pages, and it has relevant reason, but does NOT need to be applied to the contents of an ASP.checkbox or ASP.radio.

Comment: and the reason why not jquery if i may ask?

Comment: i want to modify the CSS file, and not have this information just for 1 page, but instead all within the web solution.

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Comment: @JohnnyMopp after looking at that site, would a valid selector be:   
span > (input[type='checkbox'][type='radio'] +label)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that makes sense.  So i guess i just have to override the data inside of the selectors, unless there is a default clear command which will set all the css for that type to the default variables

Comment: @Fallenreaper: The `()` aren't valid and aren't needed, but that selects a `label` that **does** follow either a checkbox or a radio button, which isn't what you want.

Comment: It's difficult to say based on your question. BoltClock's answer might be more like what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a CSS selector for an element that doesn't have a sibling of a certain kind.

But if you can guarantee that your structure is always an `input` followed by a `label`, then you *could* use the next-sibling combinator with `:not()` like so to match the `label`:

```
input:not([type="checkbox"]):not([type="radio"]) + label
```

Otherwise you're going to have to add classes to those labels, or use jQuery.

Comment: I cant access the content of the label through the ASP: checkbox control, so i would have to set a class higher up if that were the case, and then have a selector based on that.

Comment: yes, it is a reasonable, but assuming that i do that, i would still need to, if possible, set it up in a CSS file so that the information will propigate across the entire system.

Comment: There IS such a selector - next sibling selector (+) combined with attribute selector.

Comment: @Stefan: There is no such selector that makes no assumptions about the document structure, but since everybody wants to assume a document structure I'll do the same.

Comment: Well, the assumption is that the sample is representative of the entire document.

Answer (score 1):

Try adjacent sibling selector:

```
input[type='text'] + label ​{ // your styles }​​
```

You need to apply it to all predecessors you need namely. But there are not many possibilities to use label for besides checkbox and radios you don't want ;)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dWrrY/2)

Comment: @Fallenreaper it does work for me in Chrome, have you tried the fiddle?

Comment: yea, i was dbl checking the fiddle, and it does work, but you say it is not correct*

Answer (score 0):

You can select elements based on what kinds of siblings they have, IF the siblings precede your target elements. You can do however much type/selector checking you want on preceding siblings of your target.

You can kind of go backwards using `nth-last-of-type` and `nth-last-child`, but you can't do any selector checking on elements which follow your target, and the only kind of type checking you can do on following elements is counting how many there are of the same type.

So in your case you could use:

```
label {
  /* your styling here */
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label, input[type="radio"] + label {
  /* remove the styling for labels preceded by a checkbox or radio button */
}
```

Use `~` instead of `+` if you expect other elements between your inputs and labels.

Depending on what other elements might be inside the spans that you're working with, any of the ['nth' pseudoclasses](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/css3psuedoclasses) may be useful to you.

This would also work for your example, if all you care about is that the labels don't have a preceding sibling:

```
label:first-child {
  /* awesome styles */
}
```

Comment: i was trying to do this, but it seemed to not do it for some reason.  I am going to rebuild quick to see if that was the issue. I used the exact thing you typed just as above.

Comment: i want under the assumption that the empty braces would remove the styling.  Do we need to adjust this with new data, or set stuff such as font-size:""; to remove the set font-size?

Comment: empty braces won't remove styling! (that might be kinda cool though)  For the unwanted elements, you'll need to overwrite whatever styling was set for the too-large set.  And font-size: "" will not remove font-size.  You can't remove, you can only overwrite. Sorry if my pseudocode gave you the wrong impression, I meant to indicate by the comments that some code (whatever styling and un-styling you want) should go there.

Comment: thanks for the information.  I overwrote the contents, in my code, the font-size with inherit.... which will accomplish the task set before me.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted an answer to a question that I feel is extremely valuable and along the lines to what you're asking for in this question. Here is the permalink to that question/answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43132408/6167697

The key thing that is missing that may not work for your case is I propose keeping the `input`s a child only to what they need to be so that other content can be selector'd using generic sibling selectors. Hypothetically you could still keep them in the `span`, and then use the `label`s in various elements inside the `span`, and that would still allow you treat those labels separate from any others I would think. I'll copy in a code snippet for a working example that demonstrates `label` elements that are not siblings to their `input`s that can still be styled.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #262626;
  color: white;
}

.radio-button {
  display: none;
}

#filter {
  padding: 5% 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.filter-label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid green;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

main {
  clear: left;
}

.content {
  padding: 3% 10%;
  display: none;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.date {
  padding: 5px 30px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.filter-label:hover {
  background-color: #505050;
}

#featured-radio:checked~#filter .featured,
#personal-radio:checked~#filter .personal,
#tech-radio:checked~#filter .tech {
  background-color: green;
}

#featured-radio:checked~main .featured {
  display: block;
}

#personal-radio:checked~main .personal {
  display: block;
}

#tech-radio:checked~main .tech {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="featured-radio" class="radio-button" name="content-filter" checked="checked">
<input type="radio" id="personal-radio" class="radio-button" name="content-filter" value="Personal">
<input type="radio" id="tech-radio" class="radio-button" name="content-filter" value="Tech">

<header id="filter">
  <label for="featured-radio" class="filter-label featured" id="feature-label">Featured</label>
  <label for="personal-radio" class="filter-label personal" id="personal-label">Personal</label>
  <label for="tech-radio" class="filter-label tech" id="tech-label">Tech</label>
</header>

<main>
  <article class="content featured tech">
    <header>
      <h1>Cool Stuff</h1>
      <h3 class="date">Today</h3>
    </header>

    <p>
      I'm showing cool stuff in this article!
    </p>
  </article>

  <article class="content personal">
    <header>
      <h1>Not As Cool</h1>
      <h3 class="date">Tuesday</h3>
    </header>

    <p>
      This stuff isn't nearly as cool for some reason :(;
    </p>
  </article>

  <article class="content tech">
    <header>
      <h1>Cool Tech Article</h1>
      <h3 class="date">Last Monday</h3>
    </header>

    <p>
      This article has awesome stuff all over it!
    </p>
  </article>

  <article class="content featured personal">
    <header>
      <h1>Cool Personal Article</h1>
      <h3 class="date">Two Fridays Ago</h3>
    </header>

    <p>
      This article talks about how I got a job at a cool startup because I rock!
    </p>
  </article>
</main>
```

That has the added benefit of being pure CSS too! And as per the other post, here's the [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/TheThinker/ckev3tt0/) so you can play around with it yourselves.