# Select label using CSS selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm using a radio button to create tabs from CSS only. The problem I'm running into is that I can't figure out how to select the `<label>` that references the radio button. I keep the labels separate from the content so that I can lay them out as tabs:

```
<div class="tab-labels">
   <label for="tab-1">Tab 1</label>
   <label for="tab-2">Tab 2</label>
   <label for="tab-3">Tab 3</label>
</div>
```

The content panes are layed out below. The input button is kept inside the content div so that I can select it when the label is clicked.  But, I can't go in reverse:

```html
<div class="content-container">
    <div class="tab details">
        <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector" checked="checked"/>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Some content 1</p>                   
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab details">
        <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector"/>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Some content 2</p>                   
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab details">
        <input id="tab-3" type="radio" name="radio-set" class="tab-selector"/>
        <div class="content">
            <p>Some content 3</p>                    
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish and my question for this issue would be: How can I change the label background color when the radio input is clicked given this layout?

I have provided a fiddle if you want to play with this live:
http://jsfiddle.net/mjohnsonco/6KeTR/

Comment: A pure CSS solution?  Not a chance.  There's no relationship that can be established between your label and the form element with the selectors that are currently available.

Comment: @cimmanon: Not entirely true. Depending on browser support he requires he could use an attribute selector: `label[for="tab-1"] { /* rules */}` That said, he doesnt have a way to relate the state the of the radio to the state of the label, so youre right about that :-)

Comment: There's an example by CSS Tricks, the main difference with yours it's they have each label beside each related radio button instead to have it in  another div, hope it helps:

http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSTabs/radio.php

Comment: @prodigitalson Right.  It could be done if the markup was different (ie. if the label and radio were sibblings, absolutely), but it cannot be done with the OP's markup.

Comment: Yes, it is true that if the radio and label are next to each other it's possible.  I wound up reworking my layout to make this the case.  So, in short, I think the answer to my question is that it's not possible at the current time with only a pure css solution.  The input and label must be located next to each other in at least a parent/child or sibling relationship.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS selector for a checked radio button's label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431726/css-selector-for-a-checked-radio-buttons-label)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by CSS only, but only with restructured HTML and more ugly CSS.

Look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/6KeTR/16/

Here you should move all the inputs out of their containers to the place where they would immediately precede the blocks you want them to affect. In that case, you place it so you could then target the parents of the tabs and their content using `~` combinator, and some nth-child selectors like this:

```css
#tab-1:checked ~ .content-container > .tab:first-child  > .content,
#tab-2:checked ~ .content-container > .tab:nth-child(2) > .content,
#tab-3:checked ~ .content-container > .tab:nth-child(3) > .content {}
```

However, such CSS-only thingies are more like proof-of-concept — they are not that maintainable and usable as their JS counterparts. So I'd recommend using them only for fun :)

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
.bgcolor1{

background-color:#blue;

}
.bgcolor2{

background-color:green;

}
.bgcolor3{

background-color:red;

}
```

JQUERY

```
$('input[name=radio-set1]:checked', '#main').addClass(bgcolor1)

$('input[name=radio-set2]:checked', '#main').addClass(bgcolor2)

$('input[name=radio-set5]:checked', '#main').addClass(bgcolor3)
```

HTML

```
 <input id="tab-1" type="radio" name="radio-set1" class="tab-selector" checked="checked"/>
 <input id="tab-2" type="radio" name="radio-set2" class="tab-selector" checked="checked"/>
 <input id="tab-3" type="radio" name="radio-set3" class="tab-selector" checked="checked"/>

<label class="bgcolor1" for="tab-1">Tab 1</label>
<label class="bgcolor2" for="tab-2">Tab 2</label>
<label class="bgcolor3" for="tab-3">Tab 3</label>
```

Comment: Who said anything about jQuery?

Comment: Do you  think is it possible with css ? never according to my knowledge

Comment: as we know we can't select the radio button where selected using css

Comment: Yes, the question was only relevant to css, but thank you for trying.