# How to hide a label and "text"-input when "radio"-input is toggled

Tags: html, css, radio-button, label, hide

This is the code in my html file, I use CSS to make it look like an application form. I had to erase some of the tags so it would display all of the html code I typed in here.

```
<label>Member</label>
<input type="radio" name="Answer" value="Yes"/>Yes<br/>
<input type="radio" name="Answer" value="No"/>No<br/>
<label>MemberID:</label> input type="text" name="MemberID" size="30" /><br/>
<label>Password:</label> input type="text" name="Password" size="25"/><br/>
```

I want the labels 'MemberID' and 'Password' and their corresponding "text"-inputs to be hidden when the radio button 'no' is enabled. Does anyone know what solutions there are for this problem? It would be of great help!

Comment: A JSfiddle would be useful

Comment: Well, our teacher told us we're not allowed to use JavaScript..

Comment: JSFiddle doesn't require Javascript. Its a sandbox for HTML/CSS (and JS) and allows you to add your code and see the result all in the browser. It also allows you to save  the example and share a link. See: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks alot @Paulie_D , it worked! And the JSFiddle site you sent is very usefull!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to change the order of the input and label

```
<input type="radio" name="radio-choice" id="radio-choice-1" value="choice-1" />
<label for="radio-choice-1">Choice 1</label>
```

Then your css would be

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label {....}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this question: 
[CSS selector for a checked radio button's label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431726/css-selector-for-a-checked-radio-buttons-label)

```
input[type="radio"]:checked+label{ /*styles*/ }
```