# style for the parent label, when subclass radio:checked

Tags: html, css

I have such a structure:

```
  <label><input type="radio" name="r">1 Label</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="r">2 Label</label>
```

How to change a style for label, when **radio:checked** ?

UPD: At using [has-selector](http:///api.jquery.com/has-selector/) :

```
$( "label:has(input:checked)" ).addClass( "checklabel" );
```

checked element is drawn only after refresh the page.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431726/css-selector-for-a-checked-radio-buttons-label

Comment: There is no parent selector in CSS (yet). So, you can't apply a style to the label (the parent element) based on the input's state. Other solutions exist but require either JavaScript or rearranging the inputs.

Comment: Yes, I saw. But I have a different structure and i need to customize only label, which is a block.
Without js this is impossible?

Answer (score -1):

This should answer your problem. It's fairly straightforward.

[:checked psudeo-class](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/)

Comment: Thanks, but i need only for this structure.

Comment: Code needs a little bit of tweaking.

**CSS**  
`input[type=radio] + label {  
  color: #ccc;
  font-style: italic;
} 
input[type=radio]:checked + label {
  color: #f00;
  font-style: normal;
}`

**HTML**

`<input type="radio" name="r" id="lab1">
<label>1 Label</label>
<br>
<label><input type="radio" name="r" id="lab2">
<label>2 Label</label>`

Comment: Clearer, more defined questioning would have helped.