# radio button checked property not working

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I'm trying to hover effect on radio's labels as it's working fine but what i want to achieve is:

*if i select a radio button the corresponding label should have some background color*

I've tried many combinations but it doesn't work for me. Any help would be appreciated.

```css
.checkout_beautify {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: all 400ms;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
.checkout_beautify:hover {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    border-radius: 25px 4px 25px 4px;
    background: #1B1B1B;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 4ms;
    text-align: center;
}
label[for=bank_transfer]:hover {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    border-radius: 25px 4px 25px 4px;
    background: #1B1B1B;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 4ms;
    text-align: center;
}
label[for=icicipg]:hover {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    border-radius: 25px 4px 25px 4px;
    background: #1B1B1B;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 4ms;
    text-align: center;
}
/*COMBINATIONS I TRIED*/

.radio input[type="radio"]:checked {
    background: pink !important;
}
.radio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ * {
    background: pink !important;
}
```

```html
<table class="radio">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="highlight">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="payu" id="payu" checked="checked">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="payu">
                    <h3 class="checkout_beautify"><b>PAYU MONEY -  (Credit/Debit/NetBanking)</b></h3>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="highlight">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="icicipg" id="icicipg">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="icicipg">ICICI PAYMENT GATEWAY - (Credit/Debit)</label>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="highlight">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="citrus" id="citrus">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="citrus">
                    <h3 class="checkout_beautify"><b>CITRUS - (Netbanking)</b></h3>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="highlight">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="bank_transfer" id="bank_transfer">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label for="bank_transfer">
                    <h3><b>DEPOSIT IN BANK</b></h3>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have any url of the above specified problem?

Comment: With this markup, it is not possible with CSS.

Comment: I think you should put radio input and label in same td and then need to try with sibling(~) selector

Comment: [link](http://pureweave.com/checkout)  

but you need to add item first

Then see at Payment Method

Comment: you can't set parent sibling selector in css. you need to use jquery. it is best way to achieve this output.

Comment: can you let me know what i have to write in jquery code

Answer (score 1):

you have to change label parent and put into same `<td>` so css work for it,

```css
.checkout_beautify {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: all 400ms;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
.checkout_beautify:hover {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    border-radius: 25px 4px 25px 4px;
    background: #1B1B1B;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 4ms;
    text-align: center;
}
label[for=bank_transfer]:hover {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    border-radius: 25px 4px 25px 4px;
    background: #1B1B1B;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 4ms;
    text-align: center;
}
label[for=icicipg]:hover {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    border-radius: 25px 4px 25px 4px;
    background: #1B1B1B;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 4ms;
    text-align: center;
}
/*CHANGE FOLLOWING*/
.radio input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background: pink;
}
.radio input[type="radio"]:checked + label * {
    background: pink;
}

label { float:left; clear:none; }
input[type=radio] { float:left; clear:none; margin: 2px 0 0 20px; }
```

```html
<table class="radio">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="highlight">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="payu" id="payu" checked="checked">
            
                <label for="payu">
                    <h3 class="checkout_beautify"><b>PAYU MONEY -  (Credit/Debit/NetBanking)</b></h3>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="highlight">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="icicipg" id="icicipg">
            
                <label for="icicipg">ICICI PAYMENT GATEWAY - (Credit/Debit)</label>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="highlight">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="citrus" id="citrus">
            
                <label for="citrus">
                    <h3 class="checkout_beautify"><b>CITRUS - (Netbanking)</b></h3>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="highlight">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="bank_transfer" id="bank_transfer">
            
                <label for="bank_transfer">
                    <h3><b>DEPOSIT IN BANK</b></h3>
                </label>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You have to some work with css for proper layout.

---

if you want to use Jquery in your code then its good, you can easily achieve it. like,

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ghjjqd17/)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below approach but you will have to tweak your HTML.

Use `input[type="radio"]:checked+label{ background: pink !important; }` to write css for the label that immediately follows an input of type radio that is checked.

Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431788/3008050

```css
.checkout_beautify {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
    transition: all 400ms;
    border-radius: 25px;
    text-align: center;
}
.checkout_beautify:hover {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    border-radius: 25px 4px 25px 4px;
    background: #1B1B1B;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 4ms;
    text-align: center;
}
label[for=bank_transfer]:hover {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    border-radius: 25px 4px 25px 4px;
    background: #1B1B1B;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 4ms;
    text-align: center;
}
label[for=icicipg]:hover {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 45px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px dotted black;
    border-radius: 25px 4px 25px 4px;
    background: #1B1B1B;
    color: #ffffff;
    transition: all 4ms;
    text-align: center;
}
/*COMBINATIONS I TRIED*/

.radio input[type="radio"]:checked {
    background: pink !important;
}
.radio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ * {
    background: pink !important;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label{ background: pink !important; }
```

```html
<table class="radio">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="highlight">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="payu" id="payu" checked="checked">
             <label for="payu">PAYU MONEY -  (Credit/Debit/NetBanking)</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
<tr class="highlight">
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="payment_method" value="payy" id="payy">
             <label for="payy">Test</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```