# SCSS : change element style if child input is checked or not

Tags: css, sass

I have never used SCSS before and I would liketo know if it would allow me to style an element depending if the checkbox located inside is checked or not.

For instance, I have :

```
<label>
  <input type="checkbox"/>
</label>
```

and I would liketo change the content of `label::before` depending if the box is checked or not.

Does SCSS allows things like this ? If yes,how can I do it ?

The reason that led me to consider SCSS to execute this is that (if I'm not mistaking) it is indeed possible with SASS.
However since I am not familiar with SASS I'd ratherdo it with SCSS, as converting my file is apparently very easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector for a checked radio button's label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431726/css-selector-for-a-checked-radio-buttons-label)

Comment: This is about targeting a label outside the target element,  am actually trying to target the parent element, so this unfortunately doesn't apply to my situation.

Comment: Sure, but a minor restructuring of the HTML would allow you to target the label.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no CSS selector that allows one to style an element based on the state of its children.

---

**Update**: The [`:has()` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) was introduced in 2022, and is [supported by all major browsers except Firefox](https://caniuse.com/css-has) as of June 2023.

You can now style parent elements based on child state like so:

```css
label::before {
  content: 'Not checked';
}

label:has(input:checked) {
  background: yellow;
}

label:has(input:checked)::before {
  content: 'Checked!';
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 11):

I did a little change in your HTML, but I think it can really help you.

**Sass code:**

```
input[type=checkbox]
  + .checkbox-label
    color: blue
  &:checked + .checkbox-label
    color: red
    &:before
      content: ""
      border: 1px solid #a3adb3
```

```css
input[type=checkbox]+.checkbox-label {
  color: blue;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+.checkbox-label {
  color: red;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+.checkbox-label:before {
  content: "";
  border: 1px solid #a3adb3;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="cbox1" value="first_checkbox">
<label for="cbox1" class="checkbox-label">Hello world</label>
```

I have helped you in some way.

Comment: Oh shit, I stand corrected! :) I always forget about sibling selectors, damn.

Comment: Don't worry. The important thing is always the exchange of knowledge @CourtDemone :)

Comment: Yes indeed that would work ! I haven't decided switchingto sass yet, but I am considering it to implement this type of behaviour without JS. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You wouldn't be able to change the content of the label based on the state of the input, you'd need JS for that.

However, you can use pseudo selector in regular ol CSS (and SCSS by extension) to style the checkbox itself using `input:checked{}`

**EDIT**: I stand corrected, see Leonardo Costa's solution using sibling selectors.

Answer (score 1):

As of today you can use the new :has() pseudo-class as a parent selector:

```
label:has(:checked)::before {
    content: "«";
    color: blue;
}
```

Comment: except in firefox: https://caniuse.com/?search=has

Comment: By default, but it can be enabled in about:config by setting the layout.css.has-selector.enabled flag to true (See notes in the link)

Comment: yes, but it's important to note since you wouldn't want to ship it to production just yet