# Create rating star with html and css

Tags: html, css

i want to create a rate star with example my html script.
this css script run if my html script like 
`<input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-5"><label for="rating-5" class="fas fa-star"></label>` ,

but i want run like this 
`<label for="rating-5" class="fas fa-star"> <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-5"> </label>`

like the example script below and css not working

example:

```css
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
}

.star-rating input {
  display: none;
}

.star-rating {
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: table;
  width: 350px;
}

.star-rating label {
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 44px;
  color: #eee;
}

.star-rating input:not(:checked)~label:hover,
.star-rating input:not(:checked)~label:hover~label {
  color: #ffc107;
}

.star-rating input:checked {
  color: #ffc107;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/all.css" />

<div class="star-rating">
  <div class="star-input">
    <label for="rating-5" class="fas fa-star">
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-5"></label>
    <label for="rating-4" class="fas fa-star">  
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-4"></label>
    <label for="rating-3" class="fas fa-star">    
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-3"></label>
    <label for="rating-2" class="fas fa-star">       
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-2"></label>
    <label for="rating-1" class="fas fa-star">     
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-1"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

pls for help my problems thanks before and sorry for my bad english..

Comment: Could you rephrase your first sentence and use dots and/or commas please?

Comment: i done edit .. maybe u understand ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SCSS : change element style if child input is checked or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40119968/scss-change-element-style-if-child-input-is-checked-or-not)

Comment: As far as I know, you can not do that without JS. There is no way to style an item based on the child component status

Comment: u wrong this work without js..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could be the solution without using JS.

```css
 .rating {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.rating label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.rating label:last-child {
  position: static;
}

.rating label:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 5;
}

.rating label:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 4;
}

.rating label:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 3;
}

.rating label:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.rating label:nth-child(5) {
  z-index: 1;
}

.rating label input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.rating label .icon {
  float: left;
  color: transparent;
}

.rating label:last-child .icon {
  color: #000;
}

.rating:not(:hover) label input:checked ~ .icon,
.rating:hover label:hover input ~ .icon {
  color: #ffa904;
}

.rating label input:focus:not(:checked) ~ .icon:last-child {
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffa904;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/all.css" />
<form class="rating">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="stars" value="1" />
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="stars" value="2" />
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="stars" value="3" />
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>   
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="stars" value="4" />
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="stars" value="5" />
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
    <span class="fa fa-star icon"></span>
  </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Why are you voting for a solution that doesn't work correctly? When we selected, I don't think that the hover effect should exist (for the selected ones)..

Comment: @TodorMarkov Could you please let me know the exact problem with my solution as I have pointed out the issue with your answer so you can fix it. and for the hover effect, I've made it as I build for my projects, You can modify it as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

What if we take the input off the label?

**EDITED!**

**HTML:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.2/css/all.css" />

<div class="star-rating">
  <div class="star-input">
      <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-5">
    <label for="rating-5" class="fas fa-star">
    </label>
        <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-4">
    <label for="rating-4" class="fas fa-star">  
     </label>
    <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-3">
    <label for="rating-3" class="fas fa-star">    
    </label>
          <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-2">
     
    <label for="rating-2" class="fas fa-star">       
       </label>
              <input type="radio" name="rating" id="rating-1">
    <label for="rating-1" class="fas fa-star">     
     </label>
   
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: arial;
}

.star-rating input {
  display: none;
}

.star-rating {
  margin: 50px auto;
  display: table;
  width: 350px;
}

.star-rating label {
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  font-size: 44px;
  color: #eee;
}

.star-rating input:not(:checked)~label:hover,
.star-rating input:not(:checked)~label:hover~label {
  color: #ffc107;
}
.star-rating input[type="radio"]:checked ~label  
  {
  color: red!important;
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Markov88/Lp4xojyw/98/)

It seems now and the selection works. Without falling out in a special case with nth-child and etc ..

Comment: Hover is working but selected in not working.

Comment: Now working,check it.

Comment: Yes, working fine now. good work.

Comment: Its not working for the first...May be should write some css for first :///

Comment: No need to change css, just place labels after inputs.