# CSS radio selected label unique color

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have two radio buttons I want to give the same color as `:hover` when `:checked`. Can this be done using CSS or do I need an `.active` class to toggle in JS?

```css
#shopping-bag[data-toggle="buttons"] label:hover,
#shopping-bag[data-toggle="buttons"] label:checked {
  color: #3b5998;
}

#rocket[data-toggle="buttons"] label:hover,
#rocket[data-toggle="buttons"] label:checked {
  color: #d34836;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-opt btn" id="shopping-bag" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="radio shopbtn" for="shopbtn"><input id="shopbtn" name="toggler" type="radio"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-bag"></i>&nbsp;Deals</label>
</div>
<div class="btn-opt btn" id="rocket" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="radio rocketbtn" for="rocketbtn"><input id="rocketbtn" name="toggler" type="radio"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-rocket"></i>&nbsp;Buzz</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS selector for a checked radio button's label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431726/css-selector-for-a-checked-radio-buttons-label)

Comment: I don't think a label has a `:checked` state. only a input would

Comment: @Sleek Geek I need the colors to be unique. The `:checked` label color isn't the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options here would be to either use Javascript to select the parent of the input, or to just put the input right before the label and use an [adjacent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139763/what-does-the-plus-sign-css-selector-mean) to modify your label when the input is checked.

```css
#shopping-bag[data-toggle="buttons"] label:hover,
#shopping-bag[data-toggle="buttons"] input:checked + label {
  color: #3b5998;
}

#rocket[data-toggle="buttons"] label:hover,
#rocket[data-toggle="buttons"] input:checked + label {
  color: #d34836;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-opt btn" id="shopping-bag" data-toggle="buttons">
  <input id="shopbtn" name="toggler" type="radio"><label class="radio shopbtn" for="shopbtn"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-shopping-bag"></i>&nbsp;Deals</label>
</div>
<div class="btn-opt btn" id="rocket" data-toggle="buttons">
  <input id="rocketbtn" name="toggler" type="radio"><label class="radio rocketbtn" for="rocketbtn"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-rocket"></i>&nbsp;Buzz</label>
</div>
```