# How to change a "color" name when clicking it's button?

Tags: css, sass

I'm looking to display the `$colors` name depending on which color swatch button is clicked on. Here is my code to display the color swatch buttons, but I'm not sure on how I should change the `$colors` name depending on what is clicked on. A lot of big brand retailers have examples of this on their websites. [Here is an example on Urban Outfitters](https://www.urbanoutfitters.com/shop/nasa-hoodie-sweatshirt?category=movie-t-shirts&color=070&quantity=1&type=REGULAR) of what I'd like to happen when changing the color. When switching between the colors, the name changes from "Gold" to "Taupe" in this example.

```
$colors: ( 
 'color-Navy'                  #2D2F3C,
 'color-Ash'                   #EEF0F2,
 'color-Black'                 #060606,
 'color-White'                 #F6F6F6,
 'color-Charcoal'              #59545A,
);

@each $color in $colors {
 $colorName: nth($color, 1);
 $bgColor:   nth($color, 2);

#ProductSelect-option-#{$colorName} + label {
  background-color: $bgColor;
  color: $bgColor;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
 }

#ProductSelect-option-#{$colorName}:checked + label {
 border-color: #555;
 border-width: 3px;
 }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like CSS. Is this Sass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your CSS selectors are correct, you simply want to set a `color` for

```
#ProductSelect-option-#{$colorName}:checked + label
```

For example:

```
#ProductSelect-option-#{$colorName}:checked + label {
  color: $colorName;
}
```

This will update the `<label>`'s `color` whenever the corresponding checkbox is checked. Due to the use of the `:checked` pseudo-class, this will also change the colour *back* when the checkbox is unchecked.

I also note that you have the variable name in the selector. While this is fine, this may not be intentional. The key here is `:checked + label`; as long as you are targeting your checkbox correctly, the above selector will target the next `<label>`.

Comment: Would this be better with radio buttons instead? I mean, not exactly sure of the behavior but considering that only one should be selected at a time

Comment: It depends on the desired behaviour, but it would certainly be possible. In fact, it even uses the same `:checked + label` syntax! See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431788/2341603) for an example of that :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks, reading again OP's question however, I think the intention is to display the name itself, like if you select the first color it should say "Navy" on a span or something like that. I think what you do is just changing the color of the label's text to the one in the variable