# square radios highlight on checked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a radio survey question with 5 square radio buttons, but I am having trouble getting it to change color while the radio is checked or focused

I am also using Vue so it is recommended to put the input inside the label
https://codepen.io/phongoli0/pen/qBbXmoe?editors=1100

```css
.squareRadios {
  margin: 10px;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
}

.squareRadios label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.squareRadios label:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"]:focus+label {
  border: 2px dashed green;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: #4c4;
}
```

```html
<div class="squareRadios">
  <label>
        0
        <input type="radio" value="0" /></label>
  <label>
        1
        <input type="radio" value="1" /></label>
  <label>
        2
        <input type="radio" value="2" /></label>
  <label>
        3
        <input type="radio" value="3" /></label>
  <label>
        4
        <input type="radio" value="4" /></label>
  <label>
        5
        <input type="radio" value="5" /></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have the `<input type="radio">` inside your `<label>`, not next to it and the `:focus` property has to be on the `<label>` not on the `<input type="radio">` radio which is *hidden*.

The *dashed green border* on `:focus` disappears after clicking on the label because the input will hold the `:focus` after clicking on it.

Here a working live [Codepen](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/JjGrLyd) (case: input and label are siblings)

```css
.squareRadios {
  margin: 10px;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
}

.squareRadios label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.squareRadios label:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: #4c4;
}

.squareRadios label:focus {
  border: 2px dashed green;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="squareRadios">
  <input id="radio0" type="radio" value="0" name="squareradios" />
  <label tabindex="1" for="radio0">
    0
  </label>

  <input id="radio1" type="radio" value="1" name="squareradios" />
  <label tabindex="1" for="radio1">
    1
  </label>

  <input id="radio2" type="radio" value="2" name="squareradios" />
  <label tabindex="1" for="radio2">
    2
  </label>

  <input id="radio3" type="radio" value="3" name="squareradios" />
  <label tabindex="1" for="radio3">
    3
  </label>

  <input id="radio4" type="radio" value="4" name="squareradios" />
  <label tabindex="1" for="radio4">
    4
  </label>

  <input id="radio5" type="radio" value="5" name="squareradios" />
  <label tabindex="1" for="radio5">
    5
  </label>

</div>
```

**EDIT**
**New Request**:

> I am also using Vue so it is recommended to put the input inside the label.

I would use JavaScript to handle this situation: toggle a class (I used a class called "checked") on the label to add the style.

```js
var labels = document.querySelectorAll("label");

for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    labels[i].addEventListener(
        "click",
        function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            if (this.classList.contains("checked")) {
                this.classList.remove("checked");
                this.firstElementChild.checked = false;
            } else {
                var checked = document.querySelector("label.checked");
                if (checked) {
                    checked.classList.remove("checked");
                    checked.firstElementChild.checked = false;
                }
                this.classList.add("checked");
                this.firstElementChild.checked = true;
            }
        },
        false
    );
}
```

```css
.squareRadios {
  margin: 10px;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
}

.squareRadios label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.squareRadios label:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.squareRadios label.checked {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: #4c4;
}

.squareRadios label:focus {
  border: 2px dashed green;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="squareRadios">
  <label tabindex="1">
    0
    <input name="squareradios" type="radio" value="0" />
  </label>

  <label tabindex="1">
    1
    <input name="squareradios" type="radio" value="1" />
  </label>

  <label tabindex="1">
    2
    <input name="squareradios" type="radio" value="2" />
  </label>

  <label tabindex="1">
    3
    <input name="squareradios" type="radio" value="3" />
  </label>

  <label tabindex="1">
    4
    <input name="squareradios" type="radio" value="4" />
  </label>

  <label tabindex="1">
    5
    <input name="squareradios" type="radio" value="5" />
  </label>

</div>
```

Here a working live [Codepen](https://codepen.io/alezuc/pen/MWKEVNg) (case: input is inside label)

Comment: I am also using Vue so it is recommended to put the input inside the label

Comment: @yaackti, ok let me have a look at it :)

Comment: I edited my answer, I use plain JS which won't require you jQuery or others... Hope you can make use of JS in your code

Answer (score 1):

I know there are several answers already but this is exactly what you're looking for:

```css
.squareRadios {
    margin: 10px;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"] {
        opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background: red;
}

.squareRadios label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.squareRadios label:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"]:focus + label {
    border: 2px dashed green;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color: blue;
    border-color: #4c4;
}
```

```html
<div class="squareRadios">
    <input type="radio" value="0" name="my_radios"/>
    <label>0</label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="my_radios"/>
    <label>1</label>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="my_radios"/>
    <label>2</label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="my_radios"/>
    <label>3</label>
    <input type="radio" value="4" name="my_radios">
    <label>4</label>
    <input type="radio" value="5" name="my_radios"/>
    <label>5</label>
</div>
```

Now here's what I've changed to make things work:

1. Like everybody else says, you'll need to put the input and label next to each other.
2. I changed the styling of the radio buttons. I made them absolute instead of fixed and gave them a 100% width and height so they are clickable and fill out the whole label.
3. I gave each radio button a name so they would be grouped to gether and actually work like radio buttons (only 1 button can be selected, not multiple)

Comment: I am also using Vue so it is recommended to put the input inside the label

Answer (score 0):

**First** thing is that you are hiding the main circle of radio button, by setting opacity and width to 0, with this the radio button is not be able to checked.

**Second** thing *`+` symbol: It is Adjacent sibling combinator. It combines two sequences of simple selectors having the same parent and the second one must come IMMEDIATELY after the first.

```css
.squareRadios {
    margin: 10px;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"] {
    position: fixed;

}
 
 .squareRadios label {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ddd;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: 2px solid #444;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
 
.squareRadios label:hover {
    background-color: red;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"]:focus + label {
    border: 2px dashed green;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-color: blue;
    border-color: #4c4;
}
```

```html
<div class="squareRadios">


        <input type="radio" value="5" />
        <label>5</label>
</div>
```

So, remove the opacity and width properties with that your radio button can be checked and set label adjacent to input field.

*Source: *[CSS selector for a checked radio button's label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431726/css-selector-for-a-checked-radio-buttons-label)*

Answer (score 0):

Labels should be next to its thing, not wrap around it.

Second thing is that you made your radios like this:

```
  opacity: 0;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
```

If you set your opacity: 1; you see you where not really clicking on anything.

```css
.squareRadios {
  margin: 10px;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"] {
  opacity: 1;
  position: fixed;
  width: 0;
}

.squareRadios label {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif, Arial;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.squareRadios label:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"]:focus+label {
  border: 2px dashed green;
}

.squareRadios input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  background-color: blue;
  border-color: #4c4;
}
```

```html
<div class="squareRadios">

  <input type="radio" value="0" />
  <label>0</label>


  <input type="radio" value="1" checked />
  <label> 1</label>

  <label>
        2
        <input type="radio" value="2" /></label>
  <label>
        3
        <input type="radio" value="3" /></label>
  <label>
        4
        <input type="radio" value="4" /></label>
  <label>
        5
        <input type="radio" value="5" /></label>
</div>
```

Comment: OP want to change the property when radio button is checked or focused.

Comment: @AhmedAli and my snippet does what different? Its blue on checked and red on focus, I didn't change CSS

Comment: but it is not changing when user selects it.

Comment: @AhmedAli run snippet again and check label 0, read my answer and see difference in first two HTML inputs and labels. I didn't fix them all.

Comment: click on them then check if the css is changing, that's the point

Comment: if you click first checkbox  ti it gets BLUE... ! Whats your problem?

Comment: Ahmed ALi is right, in my browser (chrome) click is not working

Comment: @TimGerhard  I'm on Firefox, but checkbox is still very small in upper left corner and visible in my snippet. I pointed that problem in answer. But t can be checked.

Comment: I assume that's a browser thing then :)