# Different CSS class to active radio

Tags: css

I'm working on a website where is this project https://varincom.purple.md/proiecte/ghefest/. I use Wordpress, and to create interactive map for floors, I use a plugin, but I have a problem. I managed to make floors to be organized linearly as here https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjQnE.jpg , editing this file from the plugin https://github.com/siscanu/varincom/blob/master/image-map-pro.min.js , but what I fail is to add a different CSS class to the active floor, (line 1080 of the file .js) to be able to color it differently.
Thanks in advance to anyone who is available to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `:checked` selector for this:

```css
.radio:checked{
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<input class="radio" type="radio" />
<input class="radio" type="radio" />
```

You can also put some other styling to the radio label, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431726/css-selector-for-a-checked-radio-buttons-label).