# How to make bold label for input checked BUT not disabled (in CSS)?

Tags: html, css

I have checkboxes and radio buttons. I want what is selected (checked) to be bold.

I use "label for" in html, as advised here: [CSS selector for a checked radio button's label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431726/css-selector-for-a-checked-radio-buttons-label)

In my case my radiobutton options can be disabled (depending on other fields of the form), and if disabled I don't want them to be bold.

I see how to do this in javascript, but I am trying to find a way in CSS.

Code built from the link:

```css
:checked + label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input id="rad1" type="checkbox" name="rad" checked/><label for="rad1">Radio 1</label>
<input id="rad2" type="checkbox" name="rad"/><label for="rad2">Radio 2</label>
<input id="chkdis1" type="radio" name="chkdis" value="chkdis1" checked disabled><label for="chkdis1"> chkdis</label>
<input id="chkdis2" type="radio" name="chkdis" value="chkdis2" disabled><label for="chkdis2"> chkdis</label>
```

My solution in CSS:

```css
:checked + label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

:disabled + label {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<input id="rad1" type="checkbox" name="rad" checked/><label for="rad1">Radio 1</label>
<input id="rad2" type="checkbox" name="rad"/><label for="rad2">Radio 2</label>
<input id="chkdis1" type="radio" name="chkdis" value="chkdis1" checked disabled><label for="chkdis1"> chkdis</label>
<input id="chkdis2" type="radio" name="chkdis" value="chkdis2" disabled><label for="chkdis2"> chkdis</label>
```

What I don't like about my solution: if I put `:disabled + label` before `:checked + label`, it won't work anymore. It's only a matter of time before someone inverts both in the code and kills the expected behavior :-)

Any better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `:not()`

```css
:not(:checked)+label,
:checked:disabled+label {
  font-weight: normal;
}

:checked+label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input id="rad1" type="checkbox" name="rad" checked/><label for="rad1">Radio 1</label>
<input id="rad2" type="checkbox" name="rad" /><label for="rad2">Radio 2</label>
<input id="chkdis1" type="radio" name="chkdis" value="chkdis1" checked disabled><label for="chkdis1"> chkdis</label>
<input id="chkdis2" type="radio" name="chkdis" value="chkdis2" disabled><label for="chkdis2"> chkdis</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add a class to your label.  Although you do know what the 'C' stands for in CSS, right?

```css
:disabled + label {
  font-weight: normal;
}

:checked + .xyz{
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input id="rad1"  type="checkbox" name="rad" checked/><label class='xyz' for="rad1">Radio 1</label>
<input id="rad2"  type="checkbox" name="rad"/><label class='xyz' for="rad2">Radio 2</label>
<input id="chkdis1" type="radio" name="chkdis" value="chkdis1" checked disabled><label for="chkdis1"> chkdis</label>
<input id="chkdis2" type="radio" name="chkdis" value="chkdis2" disabled><label for="chkdis2"> chkdis</label>
```

Comment: I'd like to keep the bold effect on the radio when it's not disabled.

Comment: when it's checked or always?

Comment: when it's checked - the other solution works best :) thanks!