# JQuery and RadioButtons question

Tags: jquery, html, css, radio-button

I have a table containing radiobuttons (i.e. 3x3 grid) and I want when I select one of them the  containing the radiobutton to change colour. Following this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630057/how-do-you-make-an-html-radio-button-bold-on-select) I did this

```
<table class="table-name">
<tr>
    <td>
        <span>Some text</span>
        <input type="radio" name="some-name" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <span>Some text</span>
        <input type="radio" name="some-name" />
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

and the javascript

```
$(':radio').change(function() {           
    $('.color-1').removeClass('color-1');       
    var $td = $(this).parent('td');
    if (this.checked) {               
        $td.addClass('color-1');   
    } else {                          
        $td.removeClass('color-1');
    }
});
```

this works well on firefox. but on internet explorer it colors the previously selected 
So if I select 1,1 it stays white but when I select 1,2 then 1,1 turns blue and so on.

Any ideas?

Comment: With the .click version, I don't think that you need the "this.checked" check as the element triggering the event is always checked, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE (all versions) have a really buggy implementation of the `onChange` event on `checkboxes` and `radio buttons`.
You have to use the `onClick` event if you want to provide a solid cross-browser behaviour.

See [this link](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html#t04) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

apparently this can be solved with using

```
$(':radio').click(function() ...
```

instead of the .change. at least in terms of compatibility with ie.

anyone has a clue why change fails or most probably what I do wrong?